# When can I compare pointers to the same object in c++?

Tags: c++

For example, I have some class hierarchy (possibly, with all kinds of inheritance - public, private, public virtual, multi-inheritance, etc.):

```
class A {
  int a;
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B: public A { int b; };
class C: public virtual B { int c; };
class E: public virtual B { int e; };
class F: public C, public E { int f; };
```

Using casts I get pointers to every sub-object of the main "big" object:

```
F * f = new F;
E * e = f;
C * c = f;
B * b = f;
A * a = f;
```

What pairs of these pointers may I compare for equality (operator==) and why?
Will the comparison use delta-logic or some other technique?

What are the possible situations, when I can't compare pointers to the same complex object?
What kind of object it can be?

I expect, that all of the pointers to the same object are always equal.

Comment: *Why* do you want to compare them, that's the question.

Comment: Pointers are merely addresses, If et all you want to compare anything it can be objects pointed by the pointers, You can't compare two addresses and tell if the objects at the those locations are equal.Well err...You can...but that is so wrong.

Comment: @Als: If I do `std::cout << (e == b) << " " << e << " " << b << std::endl;`, it prints `1 0x1aaa020 0x1aaa030`. So the addresses are different, but pointers are equal. The whole question is about the common c++ rules of such kind of comparisons.

Comment: Note that there is no reason ever to use a `dynamic_cast` for an upcast: the cast will always succeed. (In fact, *no* (explicit) cast is needed here.)

Comment: @abyss.7: (e == b), stricly speaking, doesn't mean that e is equal to b. It means that e after implicit casting to B is equal to b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare two pointers if one pointer type is implicitly convertible to the other; that is, if they both point to the same type, or one points to a base class of the other's. The conversion will make the necessary adjustment to the address so that, if both pointers point to the same object, they will compare equal.

In this case, you can compare any pair except `c == e`, since neither of `C` nor `E` is derived from the other. To compare those, you would either need to cross-cast, or to convert both to their common base class; neither of these can be done implicitly.

By the way, there's no need for `dynamic_cast` in your code, since you're casting to base class pointers and that safe conversion can be done implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful here.  For example, c and e are pointers to distinct aspects of *f, and therefore are not really the same object.  Fortunately the compiler will give you an error if you try to compare c and e because one is not derived from the other.  Any other comparison in your example will work because one of the pointers can be trivially converted to the type of the other.

```
class A {
  int a;
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B: public A { int b; };
class C: public virtual B { int c; };
class E: public virtual B { int e; };
class F: public C, public E { int f; };

{
  F * f = new F;
  E * e = dynamic_cast<E*>(f);
  C * c = dynamic_cast<C*>(f);
  B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>(f);
  A * a = dynamic_cast<A*>(f);
  cerr << (a==b) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (a==c) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (a==e) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (a==f) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (b==c) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (b==e) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (b==f) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (c==e) << "\n"; // compile error
  cerr << (c==f) << "\n"; // true
  cerr << (e==f) << "\n"; // true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to ensure that two pointers (possibly of diffrent type) point to the same object, use

```
dynamic_cast<void*>(pointer1) == dynamic_cast<void*>(pointer2)
```

Of course, both pointer types should be polimorphic to provide correct dynamic_cast

If the class hierarchy has a single (possibly virtual) root, 
it's possible to cast both poiners to pointers to the root class and then compare two results (without dynamic casting)

Comment: @Konrad: Why doesn't make sense? If downcasting for both pointers yeld the same address, then they point to the same object (and vise versa). If pointer types are not convertable to each other (or some root class), I don't know other way to check it except of dynamic_cast (although may be it is not excactly the OP's question..)

Comment: @Konrad: my code checks that both pointer1 and pointer2 being (down)casted to most derived class refer to the same object (I don't pretend that this strictly answers the OP's question)

Comment: After reading up on the standard (prompted by your new question) I take everything back. I wasn’t aware (and pretty damn sure of the opposite) that the standard made extra provisions for (cv qualified) `void*` in a `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only compare pointers of the same type.  However, you don't always need an explicit cast to do so.  In the simple case:

```
B * pB = new B();
A * pA = pB;

if (pA == pB)  {}  //pB is implicitly cast to an A *
```

When you get to more complex classes, you will need to add explicit casts so

```
F * pF = new F();
C * pC = dynamic_cast<C *>(pF)
A * pA1 = dynamic_cast<A *>(pF);
A * pA2 = dynamic_cast<A *>(pC);

//should all be true
if (pF == dynamic_cast<F *>(pA)) {}
if (pA1 == dynamic_cast<A *>(pF)) {}
if (pA1 == pA2) {}
```

Comment: The examples worked without the need for `dynamic_cast`. The implicit cast in `==` was sufficient.